# Solrdocument.addfield replace the document instead of updating the fields

Tags: solr

iam trying to update 3 fields to solrj using solrinputdocument.addField("fieldname", "fieldvalue");
it generally replaces the complete document instead of updating these fields alone. Iam using solr 4.5 and iam not sure what is the issue. i also tried with setfield for solrinputdocument.setField and it didnt work.
Please help. The sample code is :

```
String urlString = "http://serverip/solr/taag_webproducts/";
SolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(urlString);

UpdateRequest up = new UpdateRequest("/update");
solrinputdocument.addField(fieldname, fieldvalue);
 up.add(solrinputdocument);
 solr.request(up);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the **_version_** field defined in schema.xml:

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

and also have an **id** field when assembling the **SolrInputDocument** (like the following example)

To do the atomic update/partial update, the map is the key

```
Map oper = new HashMap();
oper.put("set", 100);

SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("id", "unique");
doc.addField("price", oper);

SolrServer server = getSolrServer();
server.add(doc);
server.commit();
```

Example taken from [solrj-4-0-0-alpha-atomic-updates](http://www.mumuio.com/solrj-4-0-0-alpha-atomic-updates/)

Comment: thanks and i read that document . I have one query regarding this. i have single values for all 3 fields which i need to update. Why do we need to use hashmap to put values here?

Comment: Iirc, that's nessary for an atomic update. Otherwise the whole record will be replaced instead of partial update.  Additional requirement is that all fields have to be configured as *stored*. The partial update will read these stored fields, update them, and then replace the old record.

Comment: for my 3 fields iam getting the document as solrdocument:SolrInputDocument(fields: [id={set=student.html}, active={set=yes}, name={set=mee}]) and solr server gives me exception saying invalid update of id={set=student.html}

Comment: Id field should be left alone, since it tells which doc to be updated.  I.e doc.addField("id","student.html")

Comment: yeah but iam getting the id from parsing one xml document. the xml document gives me these 3 fields along with id.any better way to do this?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't make it clear... the id field do not need to use the map to set the value, while the other 3 fields do.

Comment: Yeah thanks..It seems to work now:) But can you explain me what is the magic of Hashmap here? i really  could not understand because we have setfield for solrinputdocument also. like solrinputdocument.setfield..but that doesnt work. why so?

Comment: I think what solrj does is to assemble a http request to solr, like the following: curl -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"add":{"doc":{"id":"1","price":{"set":1000}}}}' http://localhost:8080/solr/update?commit=true   the content specified in the -d is what the SolrInputDocument need to assemble.